# I can't run Flutter from CMD after adding the Flutter bin path in Environment Variable

Tags: flutter, cmd

I am trying to setup a path variable for Flutter on my PC. After adding the full path below to the bin folder, when I run the following command in CMD "`flutter --version`", I get the following result:

> 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Path: `C:\Users\Netchoice\AppData\Roaming\npm; C:\Flutter\flutter\bin`

Can someone help me understand why I can't run Flutter from cmd, after adding the flutter bin folder unto the path? Is there something I did wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have `C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat`?

Comment: Where are you executed `flutter --version` command?

Comment: Hi Randal,  No I don't have C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat?

Comment: @farten,, I am executing the command as follows: C:\WINDOWS\system32>flutter --version